# Zapier POST with error "body used already for"

Tags: fetch-api, zapier

Basically following the [code example](https://zapier.com/help/code/) verbatim, but trying to make a POST request with [fetch](https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch/tree/32b60634434a63865ea3f79edb33d17e40876c9f?utm_source=zapier.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=zapier#usage)

```
fetch('YOUR URL HERE', { method: 'POST', 'body': content })
    .then(function (res) {
        console.log(res.text());
        return res.text();
    })
    .then(function (plain) {
        var output = { okay: true, raw: plain };
        callback(null, output);
    })
    .catch(callback);
```

Results in angry red box with:

> We had trouble sending your test through. Please try again. Error: 
>   Error: **body used already for**: https://YOURURLHERE

Not sure what it means?

Answer (score 23):

...and then I realized it's not a Zapier question, but a `fetch` issue.

[Google](https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch/issues/347) says it's because of what I'm doing in the *promise*, by trying to read the `res` stream as text twice (note the two `res.text()` calls).

*(for about 2 minutes I had omitted what I thought was an unimportant detail from the question, the `console.log` line which was the culprit)*

Comment: That's right! You could achieve the same result with `console.log(plain)`